# Trying to suppress URLs with BibLaTeX, using a simple person's method

Tags: biblatex, urls

Based on other questions here, I'm trying to create an annotated bibliography, using `\fullcite`, where I want to suppress all URLs.

I'm using what appears to be a simple solution, which works for a 'normal' bibliography, but not for `\fullcite` (I've included the normal bibliography for illustration):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mwe82.bib}
@MANUAL{wilson2009,
  author = {Peter Wilson},
  title = {A Few Notes on Book Design},
  year = {2009},
  organization = {The Herries Press},
  url = {http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/memdesign/memdesign.pdf},
  address = {Normandy Park, WA},
  urlaccessdate = {19.12.2012}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[%
    citestyle=authoryear, 
    bibstyle=authoryear, 
    backend=biber,
    bibencoding=utf8,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe82.bib}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \clearfield{url}%
    }
\begin{document}
\fullcite{wilson2009}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Giving this:

[image: output pdf]

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you can use `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{url}}`

Comment: I was just about to say the same thing....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are different approaches.

First on LaTeX-level you can use

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{url}}
```

`\AtEveryBibitem` works only for `\printbibliography`.

Or you use a Biber solution:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
 \maps[datatype=bibtex ]{
   \map{
     \step [ fieldset = url , null ]
     }
  }
}
```

---

MWE:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mwe82.bib}
@MANUAL{wilson2009,
  author = {Peter Wilson},
  title = {A Few Notes on Book Design},
  year = {2009},
  organization = {The Herries Press},
  url = {http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/memdesign/memdesign.pdf},
  address = {Normandy Park, WA},
  urlaccessdate = {19.12.2012}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[%
    citestyle=authoryear, 
    bibstyle=authoryear, 
    backend=biber,
    bibencoding=utf8,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe82.bib}
\DeclareSourcemap{
 \maps[datatype=bibtex ]{
   \map{
     \step [ fieldset = url , null ]
   }
 }
}
\begin{document}
\fullcite{wilson2009}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Marco, `\EveryCitekey` is what I was looking for, but it's nice to have the `biber` tweak in my first-aid kit as well...