# Biblatex journal name non-italic

Tags: biblatex

I want to make journal names nonitalic using biblatex. Is there a way to do this using DeclareFieldFormat?

I could change article names to italics using DeclareFieldFormat and I want to make journal names nonitalic in a similar way. I use

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backend=biber, giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
\labelelement{
\field[final]{shorthand}
\field{label}
\field[strwidth=2, strside=left, ifnames=1]{labelname}
\field[strwidth=1, strside=left]{labelname}
}
    }
\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{#1}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{first-last}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\addspace}%
}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\textit{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\textit{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*[article]{title}{\textit{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book]{title}{\textit{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*[article]{citetitle}{\textit{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book, thesis]{citetitle}{\textit{#1}}
\bibliography{sample}


\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

When I run this all of the journal names (of articles) in sample.bib are shown in italics.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a small compilable code?

Comment: `\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1\isdot}` so pretty much using the same strategy as for `title`s, but keeping in mind that the `journal` field is internally called `journaltitle`.

Comment: Thanks @moewe. It worked. If you answer below I will accept as answer.

Comment: I'd also suggest `\mkbibitalic` (or `\mkbibemph`) instead of `\textit` in bibliography-related stuff like `\DeclareFieldFormat`

Comment: I have another quick question `[url=false]` for biblatex is not working to remove URL tag on online references. Is there a way to getting rig of URL tag?

Comment: Ah no, replace `\textit` by `\mkbibitalic` or `\textit{#1}` by `\mkbibitalic{#1}`. `url=false` does not remove the URLs for `@online` entries by design since it is assumed that they somehow need to retain a URL even if it is suppressed for other types (given that an `@online` entry could potentially have a DOI or an `eprint` it does not necessarily need a URL to make sense, so that assumption may be seen as infelicitous, but that's how it is). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113039/35864 for more radical solutions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Internally the `journal` field is called `journaltitle` (to be precise, the field is called `journaltitle` and `journal` is only an alias that gets automatically remapped to `journal`). So you need to redefine the field format for `journaltitle`

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1\isdot}
```

I also suggest you use

```
\mkbibitalic
```

instead of `\textit` in `\DeclareFieldFormat` directives. You could also use `\mkbibemph` if you want to allow toggling between italics and upright font.

---

In the MWE you seem to misuse the starred version of `\DeclareFieldFormat`. The starred version clears all type-specific formatting, so directly using the optional type argument seem superfluous. The entire block with redefinitions for `title` and `citetitle` can probably be compressed down to

```
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibitalic{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{\mkbibitalic{#1}}
```

---

`\DeclareNameAlias{author}{first-last}` should be replaced by

```
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{given-family}
```

but that should be the default setting, so should not be necessary at all.

---

Finally, `finalnamedelim` need usually not be redefined in `\DefineBibliographyExtras` and should nowadays be redefined using the context sensitive delimiter interface. In your case I guess the cleanest approach would be

```
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}
```

Comment: Thanks, that answer saved my day.