# Turkish bibliography styling

Tags: biblatex, turkish

I am citing a journal paper. I use this code:

```
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{my_references.bib}
\printbibliography[title={Kaynakça}]
```

It returns:

> Yıldırım, Ali ve diğ. (2009). “Tokat ili merkezinde çalı ̧san hekimlerin tıbbi uygulama hataları ile ilgili bilgi, tutum ve davranısları”. Içinde: *Cumhuriyet Medical Journal* 31.4, ss. 356–366.

However, I don't want to have a parenthesis covering the year like this (2009) -> 2009.
I want to remove this "Içinde: "
and I want to have this *Cumhuriyet Medical Journal* being without italic.

How can I do this?

Chatgpt suggested to have this:

```
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{year}
    {}
    {\printtext{\printdate}}}
```

but it did not work.

I am using overleaf.

Comment: Welcome. // Two ways to make progress here, at least: 1) Have a look at the **Related** table to the right, 2) click on tag *turkish* . And of course: there's a search field on top of this site.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this helpful comment. I searched my question but couldn't find a helpful answer. @MS-SPO

Comment: Ok, last hint, as comments here are for clarification, not for discussion: What are you looking for? Modifying a bibliograpic style (regardless of language). So your next search key would be, here or worldwide: ... Modifying a bibliograpic style biblatex, and turkish may be worth a try. But if you see how to do it in English, the rest should be simle enough.

Comment: For the parentheses see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428190/35864. For the "Içinde", see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864. For the `journaltitle` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/454672/35864.

Comment: @moewe thanks a lot. I reviewed my latex code and shared as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

## before begin document

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, sorting=nyt, maxcitenames=2, mincitenames=1, maxbibnames=999, giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}
}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\addbibresource{my_references.bib}
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit*{\adddot\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{} 
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{``#1''\addcomma}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1\addcomma}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{turkish}{%
  andothers = {vd\adddot}
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given} % For newer versions of BibLaTeX
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}
```

## to put references

```
\printbibliography[title={Kaynakça}]
```

## Template code

```
\documentclass[tikz,a4paper,9pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, sorting=nyt, maxcitenames=2, mincitenames=1, maxbibnames=999, giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}
}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\addbibresource{my_references.bib}
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit*{\adddot\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{} 
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{``#1''\addcomma}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1\addcomma}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{turkish}{%
  andothers = {vd\adddot}
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given} % For newer versions of BibLaTeX
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}
\begin{document}
Citation: \cite{yildirim2009tokat}

\printbibliography[title={Kaynakça}]  % This prints your bibliography section with the title "Kaynakça (References)"
\end{document}
```

## .bib file for the reference

```
@article{yildirim2009tokat,
  title={Tokat ili merkezinde {\c{c}}al{\i}{\c{s}}an hekimlerin t{\i}bbi uygulama hatalar{\i} ile ilgili bilgi, tutum ve davran{\i}{\c{s}}lar{\i}},
  author={Y{\i}ld{\i}r{\i}m, Ali and Aksu, Murat and {\c{C}}etin, {\.I}lhan and {\c{S}}ahan, Abdulkadir},
  journal={Cumhuriyet Medical Journal},
  volume={31},
  number={4},
  pages={356--366},
  year={2009}
}
```

## output

[image: citation]

[image: reference]

Comment: Fine + Welcome. // Can you please add the missing lines to compile a simple example? This adds a lot of value to future readers. Thank you

Comment: @MS-SPO I added a template to run.

Comment: Fine. // Off-topic: „Template“ nowadays seems to be a buzz word or an empty filler … Just wondering.